# Is minimality of finite extension equivalent to minimality of base structure?

Tags: model-theory

First, some inspiration for this question. The structure $(\mathbb{R}^{+};\cdot)$ of non-negative reals under multiplication is a superstructure of $(\mathbb{R}^{++};\cdot)$, which is the structure of positive reals under multiplication. Both structures are minimal, meaning, parameter-definable subsets of the structures are either finite or cofinite. Inspired by this, let $M$ and $N$ be structures such that $M$ is a substructure of $N$, and also such that the universe of $N$ has only finitely many more elements than the universe of $M$. Is $M$ minimal if and only if $N$ is minimal? If not, does at least one direction of the equivalence hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $M$ is a cofinite substructure of $N$. It's certainly true that if $N$ is minimal then $M$ must be minimal, since every definable subset of $M$ is also definable in $N$ - this is because $M$ itself is definable in $N$, via a finite tuple enumerating $N\setminus M$. So a counterexample to minimality of $M$ also gives a counterexample to minimality of $N$.

The other direction, however, fails badly. For example, suppose $\mathcal{G}$ is **any** graph (= $\{E\}$-structure for $E$ a binary relation symbol) whatsoever. Then letting $T$ be a ternary relation symbol we can whip up a pair of $\{T\}$-structures $M\subseteq N$ such that the domain of $M$ is that of $\mathcal{G}$, the domain of $N$ is that of $M$ + a single new element $\star$, and we have $$T^N=\{(\star,a,b): (a,b)\in E^\mathcal{G}\}.$$ Then $T^M=T^N\cap M^3=\emptyset$ so $M$ is just a pure set, but $N$ is as complicated as $\mathcal{G}$.